# How to read a discontinues signal from workspace in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, integrator

I have a standard validation signal and want to read it from workspace as the input of my model in Simulink and then compare the output of model with the one from measurements. As it is a validation signal I can not change the signal in order to remove the discontinuities. Whenever I try to run the model I receive a error regarding the singularity problems over the integrator blocks in my model, because of having discontinuities.  Derivative input 1 of 'laplace_domain_test_V2/ct & dl & Warburg/Integrator' at time 140.0042 is Inf or NaN. Stopping simulation. There may be a singularity in the solution. If not, try reducing the step size (either by reducing the fixed step size or by tightening the error tolerances)  I tried to reduce the step size to very small values & tightening the error tolerance and also to change the solver to the stiff ones but the problem is still unfixed. Can any one please suggest a way to get rid of this error?

I really appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Which solver are you using?

Comment: Generally is a good aproach to set the solver to ODE1 whe this happens and you dont know why. ODE1 is very simple and will not create numerical inestabilities, tehrefore if it doesnt work with ODE1 means you are dividing by zero or trying to solve something unsolvable.If it does work with ODE1 means that yhe solver you are using creates nnumerical insetabilities (sometimes it happens, welcome to  numerical analysis).

Comment: Thanks Ander for response. Sorry for being late, I just noticed your answer.I tried with all of the solvers, but still the problem with singularity exists! Another problem is that I do not have any idea of the suitable value for max/min step size or the absolute/relaative error tolerance. do you have any suggestion for that?  thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: My understanding, possibly imperfect, is that when Simulink detects a discontinuity, as in your input signal, it reduces the time steps to small values about the discontinuity to get an approximate derivative. Sometimes, however, there are large fluctuations around the discontinuity, and zero crossing detection will not resolve them. If this is the case in your model, perhaps you can turn off zero crossing? [More details here](http://www.itu.dk/stud/speciale/segmentering/Matlab6p5/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/how_simulink_works14.html)